# Copying folders using cmd & MSSQL script

Tags: sql, sql-server, cmd, xcopy

I'm trying to copy one folder into another folder but I'm getting errors,

I've wrote following SQL script:

```
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(1000)
    DECLARE @Dt DATETIME
    SET @Dt = GETDATE()
    SET @SQL = 'xcopy "C:\test\" "D:\test\backup '+DATENAME ( day , @Dt )+''+LEFT(DATENAME ( month , @Dt ),3)+''+DATENAME ( year , @Dt )+''+REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 100),7),':','.')+'-'+DATENAME ( s , @Dt )+'\" /e /i /h '
    PRINT @SQL
    EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @SQL
```

I'm getting following error

```
Invalid path
```

Comment: Have you validated the xcopy statement (produced by your PRINT statement) works directly on command prompt?

Comment: I checked in cmd, i get the same error 'Invalid path'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yea, its working now, I used `*.*` at the end of source path.

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @Dt DATETIME
SET @Dt = GETDATE()
SET @SQL = 'xcopy "C:\test\*.*" "D:\test\backup '+DATENAME ( day , @Dt )+''+LEFT(DATENAME ( month , @Dt ),3)+''+DATENAME ( year , @Dt )+''+REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 100),7),':','.')+'-'+DATENAME ( s , @Dt )+'\" /e /i /h '
PRINT @SQL
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @SQL
```